# If the index is greater than arr length it should go back round again

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function getAnyItem(arr, position) {
  if (position > arr.length) {
   return position = arr[0] ;
  }
  let index = arr[position];
  return index;

 }
```

I am really struggling on finding a way to go back round an array without using loops.Above is what I have written so far, all I get it undefined.
Any help would be much appreciated as I am new to coding.

getItem(['a','b','c'], 10) should return 'b'

Comment: `return arr[position % arr.length]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) with the length of the array

```js
function getItem(arr, position) {
   return arr[position % arr.length];
}

console.log(getItem(['a','b','c'], 10)); // 'b'
```